# Converting a string in data frame into separate columns and then add them back to the main data frame

Tags: python, json, dataframe, api, etl

I am writing an ETL script that is sourcing data from an API. My aim is to load the final dataset into a MySQL database. Below is a snapshot of the JSON am getting from the API endpoint [JSON Response Image from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deT1l.png)

JSON data for testing

```
{
    'count': 9840,
    'rows': [{
                'id': 1,
                'closed': 1,
                'closedAt': '2019-09-18T18:39:33Z',
                'disposition': 'unmanaged',
                'formData': '{"body":"name: kamaro\\nemail: testing@testing.com\\n","referer":"https://staging.https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/","customerIp":"xxx.xxx.xx.xx","mapKey":"email","from":"testing@testing.com","firstName":"testing@testing.com","ListId":1,"email":"testing@testing.com"}',
                'createdAt': '2019-09-18T18:39:33Z'
            }, {
                'id': 2,
                'closed': 1,
                'closedAt': '2019-09-23T13:10:44Z',
                'disposition': 'unmanaged',
                'formData': '{"body":"name: KAMAZA\\nemail: 333xxxxxl@sdfa.com\\n","referer":"https://staging.https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/","customerIp":"xxx.xxx.xx.xx","mapKey":"email","from":"Lmbaxxxxx.com","firstName":"yyyyyyl@sdfa.com","ListId":1,"email":"yyyyyyl@sdfa.com"}',
                'createdAt': '2019-09-23T13:05:44Z'
            }, {
                'id': 3,
                'closed': 1,
                'closedAt': '2019-10-11T11:23:56Z',
                'disposition': None,
                'formData': '{"body":"name: customer name\\nemail: yyyyyy@gmail\\n","referer":"https://staging.https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/","customerIp":"xxx.xx.13.79","mapKey":"email","from":"yyyyyy@gmail"}',
                'createdAt': '2019-10-11T10:55:19Z'
            }, {
                'id': 4,
                'closed': 1,
                'closedAt': '2019-10-11T11:59:12Z',
                'disposition': 'timeout',
                'formData': '{"body":"name: Pamphtest\\nemail: pamphilexxxx.co\\n","referer":"https://staging.https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/","customerIp":"xxx.xx.143.94","mapKey":"email","from":"pamphilexxxx.co","firstName":"pamphilexxxx.co","ListId":1,"email":"pamphilexxxx.co"}',
                'createdAt': '2019-10-11T11:27:32Z'
            }, {
                'id': 5,
                'closed': 1,
                'closedAt': '2019-10-11T14:06:12Z',
                'disposition': 'timeout',
                'formData': '{"body":"name: Pamphile\\nemail: Pamphile@gama.com\\n","referer":"https://staging.https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/","customerIp":"xxx.xx.13.79","mapKey":"email","from":"Pamphile@gama.com","firstName":"Pamphile@gama.com","ListId":1,"email":"Pamphile@gama.com"}',
                'createdAt': '2019-10-11T13:35:11Z'
            },
            {
            "id": 9806,
            "closed": 1,
            "closedAt": "2021-03-18T13:08:10Z",
            "formData": "{\"body\":\"New chat request \\nEmail Address: daudiXXXXXC@gmail.com\\nWhat is your gender?: Female\\nWhat is your age range?: 20-24 years\\nDo you use contraceptives?: No\\nWhat is your location?: Nairobi\\nTo use this service: true\\n\",\"referer\":\"https://xxxxxxxxxx.com\",\"customerIp\":\"xxxxxxxxxx\",\"mapKey\":\"email\",\"from\":\"daudiXXXXXC@gmail.com\",\"email\":\"daudiXXXXXC@gmail.com\",\"cf_1\":\"Female\",\"cf_2\":\"20-24 years\",\"cf_13\":\"No\",\"cf_14\":\"Nairobi\",\"cf_15\":true,\"firstName\":\"daudiXXXXXC@gmail.com\",\"ListId\":1}",
            "createdAt": "2021-03-18T13:03:09Z"
        }
```

I have managed to convert the JSON into a data frame Using the python script below

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import pandas as pd

my_response = requests.get('https://mydomain.io/api/xxx/interactions?fields=formData,closedAt,id,closed,'
                                  'disposition,createdAt,updateAT',auth = HTTPBasicAuth('myname', 'mypassword'))
my_data = dict(my_response.json())
my_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(my_data['rows'])
```

The challenge I am  facing is converting the keys inside the **formData** into columns and have those new columns be part of the main data frame. Please see the two photos showing my current results and my desired results
[My current dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeD7x.png)

[My desired dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5L9ki.png)

Comment: Give the json **as text**, replacing sensitive data with what you want. With images, we cannot copy and paste to test possible ways.

Comment: Hi Serge I have added the Json

Comment: HI  @SergeBallesta If I do `my_data.update(json.loads(my_data['formData']))`
 am getting an error  KeyError: 'formData'.

I have tried to access dataform key  as below ,it works but when I go ahead and update the my_data I get None when I print the results
`my_data = dict(my_response.json())
my_new_data = json.loads(my_data['rows'][0]['formData'])
print(my_data.update(my_new_data))`.Any ideas ?.Thanks for the help

Comment: The sample Json you show in your question does not contain `rows`. If you show a wrong json, I cannot guess what the actual json contains...

Comment: Hi @SergeBallesta the reason for me to omit rows was I had already filtered it from the response when creating the data frame.I dint know it will affect the whole solution but it seems it does .Please find the a section of the actual json when I print the response without selecting only rows   `my_data = dict(my_response.json())` .Please note the "formData' has different keys depending on what the customer filled in .Thank you so much for investing your time to help

Comment: I have also realized this morning the `formData` is dictionary .I tried to use json.normalize  as below 

`my_not_nested_dataframe= pd.json_normalize(my_data_frame,record_path=['formData'])`

but am getting this error  `Must be list or null.`

Answer (score 0):

You have a json where the relevant part is a list of dicts. Nothing hard till there. The specificity is that those dicts contain a json string which has to be decoded. Then `update` is enough to bring the inner dict keys and values at the level of the containing keys. Once this is done, you can just build your dataframe from the list of dicts.

Code could be:

```
my_response = requests.get(
    'https://mydomain.io/api/xxx/interactions?fields=formData,closedAt,id,closed,'
    'disposition,createdAt,updateAT',auth = HTTPBasicAuth('myname', 'mypassword'))
my_data = my_response.json()

my_data = my_data['rows']           # only process the rows part
for d in my_data:                   # but extract the inner json strings for all dicts
    d.update(json.loads(d['formData']))

# build the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(my_data, columns=['id', 'closed', 'closedAt', 'email', 'cf_1'
                                   'cf_2', 'cf_14', 'cf_13', 'createdAt'])
```

With the shown data, it gives:

```
     id  closed              closedAt                  email  cf_1cf_2    cf_14 cf_13             createdAt
0     1       1  2019-09-18T18:39:33Z    testing@testing.com       NaN      NaN   NaN  2019-09-18T18:39:33Z
1     2       1  2019-09-23T13:10:44Z       yyyyyyl@sdfa.com       NaN      NaN   NaN  2019-09-23T13:05:44Z
2     3       1  2019-10-11T11:23:56Z                    NaN       NaN      NaN   NaN  2019-10-11T10:55:19Z
3     4       1  2019-10-11T11:59:12Z        pamphilexxxx.co       NaN      NaN   NaN  2019-10-11T11:27:32Z
4     5       1  2019-10-11T14:06:12Z      Pamphile@gama.com       NaN      NaN   NaN  2019-10-11T13:35:11Z
5  9806       1  2021-03-18T13:08:10Z  daudiXXXXXC@gmail.com       NaN  Nairobi    No  2021-03-18T13:03:09Z
```

As you can see, it is easy to only select some keys from the dataframes by giving an explicit list of columns. Adapt that part if you have other interesting columns in your real dataset.

Comment: @oyugi.collins With the actual Json, I could provide an updated answer...